# Get access to shared preferences of another application

Tags: android, android-intent

I call different application from my with code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.mypackage","com.mypackage.UI.SplashActivity"));
intent.putExtra("URI", path);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the called application there is code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
int currentResolution = prefs.getInt(Values.CURRENT_RESOLUTION_SETTING, 1200);
```

It always gives me 1200. I think it is because of that I dont launch application directly. How to get access to the preferences?

Comment: You should read the docs about shared prefs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Waqas says is correct, you can't use another applications data/shared preference unless it's shared somehow. But if you have access to both applications you should not use:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
```

As the default uses MODE.PRIVATE which means you can only read the shared preference from the app it's initialized in.

If you have access to both applications you could use either:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues();
```

In order to change the default mode or use a preference with a name and mode and instead of getting the default use:

```
getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE);
```

You can read more in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html) and maybe figure out if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, you cannot access data of other applications unless:

- The application itself provides an interface (like `ContentResolver`,
  Broadcasts or Service binding) to make its data available
- Your device is rooted, so you access its data files with *SuperUser* permissions

Comment: Since Android 8 Broadcasts and Services can't be used for background work in most use cases. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html has to be used. Fuck me I guess.

Comment: @Redwolf Can you please provide official reference to support your statement?

Comment: As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits, apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest. However, several broadcasts are currently exempted from these limitations. Apps can continue to register listeners for the following broadcasts, no matter what API level the apps target. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html ContentResolver might work though ... until Google gets new ideas.

Comment: Here is the part about the JobScheduler: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts

Comment: The limitations are on **implicit broadcasts** if registered in **manifest**. It doesn't stop you from using Services and register such broadcasts internally via code e.g. `Context.registerReceiver()`. `Service` has its own significance and cannot be totally replaced by `JobScheduler`. Both serve different purposes but may overlap at some points.